# cant decrypt a file in c#, the resulting file is corrupted

Tags: c#, encryption

I created some code in visual studio to download a file using ftp download methods and then i tried to create the code to decrypt it when ia realized that the files where encrypted (i have the key and IV) so i tried to make code to decrypt the file but the result is corrupted)

```
private static void DecryptFile(string path, string newpath, string skey)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged() { 
                KeySize = 128,
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC

            })
            {
                byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey);


                byte[] IV = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey);

                using (FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
                        {
                            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                int data;
                                while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                {
                                    fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // failed to decrypt file
        }
    }
```

Comment: Chances are the error is in the FTP methods (binary vs text mode).

Comment: Always make sure you test 1 things at a time.

Comment: first make a sample program to encrypt decrypt file. then test with ftp

Comment: Using the same value for the key and IV defeats the purpose of CBC and make you vulnerable.